# FederatedAuthentication CanReadSignInResponse causes a potentially dangerous request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ws-federation

I have an action with

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var module = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

    // exception in the line bellow
    if (module.CanReadSignInResponse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request, true))
    {
    }
}
```

When I call the method it throws an exception saying the request is potentially dangerous. We send a XML on the post.

Stack trace:

[image: stacktrace]

Even with the attribute `[ValidateInput(false)]` on the action this exception occurs.

Any idea why it happens? Is there a way to prevent it?